# find selector used jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-selectors, jquery-selectors

I am making a jQuery plugin, and I was wondering if there was a way that I could find the selector that the user uses to apply the plugin. For example, if the user selects this:

```
$(".myClass").pluginName();
```

Then the plugin will return `myClass`, which can then be used later. Is there a way I can do this?

Comment: Why would you do that? Surely storing a reference to the selected element, in the plugin instance, is more useful. If you meant the return from your `pluginName()` call, that would break standard jQuery chaining.

Comment: And how can I do that?

Comment: jQuery has a way to do this, because it was used by `.live()`. But I don't think it's meant to be used by applications. They might even have removed it after `.live` was removed.

Comment: @yak613 The elements are in `this`.

Comment: Question: What are you intending to do with the selector later? That may well change the question (as it is currently a little vague).

Comment: Anything you need other than the elements that the plugin was applied to should be in the options argument to the plugin. So you could do `$(selector).pluginName({ class: "myClass" });`

Comment: FWIW, the documentation on the deprecated property [.selector](https://api.jquery.com/selector/) says "Plugins that need to use a selector string within their plugin can require it as a parameter of the method."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose this is your selection :

```
var $selection = $('a, i');
```

If you want to get the selector, just use the `selector` property :

```
var selector = $selection.selector;
```

In this case, the value of the `selector` variable would be the string `a, i`.

---

#### NOTE :

While the `selector` property is included in jQuery 1.11.0 and jQuery 2.1.3, it appears to be missing from jQuery 3.0.0 alpha1. This is probably why :

> The `.selector` property was deprecated in jQuery 1.7 and is only
>   maintained to the extent needed for supporting `.live()` in the jQuery
>   Migrate plugin. It may be removed without notice in a future version.
>
> [**source**](https://api.jquery.com/selector/)

If you can think of a good reason why this feature should stay in the jQuery core, you might want to make an appeal to the jQuery dev team and request they change their decision to remove the feature.

Answer (score 1):

Inspecting the jQuery object in the debugger, it has an attribute `selector` that contains the selector used to create the set.  I don't know if this is public API that you can count on remaining available in future releases or if this is an implementation detail that may change without warning.

Like the other commenters, I question the need to reference the selector.  In your plugin you can simply iterate through all of the selected elements without performing the search through the DOM again.  Just use `this.each()` in your plugin.